# Change my cursor pointer to a custom cursor

Tags: css, mouse-cursor

I saw this topic but it wasn't of any help: "html, css - cursor - how to change default image for pointer".

Is there any way I can use CSS to resolve this issue, b/c I'm not allowed to use JScript on someone else's website where I am configuring my profile on. I can only use CSS Markup and HTML Markup. There can't be a way to use JScript in the CSS Markup, right?

Description: When the arrow cursor is over other elements, the pointer cursor pops in and I need that pointer cursor changed to a custom cursor.

This is the cursor I want:

[image]

What may work, but I don't how to put it in my code below and nor do I know what to replace (my_cursor.svg) with: body {   cursor: url(my_cursor.svg), auto; }

```
body , html { 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
    background: #000 url('http://1hdwallpapers.com/wallpapers/undead_dragon.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;  
    background-size:contain; 
    cursor: url('http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-view/21962.png'), url('cute25.cur'), help; 
}

div#mask { 
    cursor: not-allowed;
    z-index: 999; 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: You're code works, just needed to be cleaned up http://jsfiddle.net/q3mjpfeg/

Comment: Ps, try to avoid repeating the question on Stackoverflow, you'll notice people write duplicate on questions because it's generally the goal to not repeat questions when suitable answers have been given =) Just informing you.

Comment: Oh! I got it. The problem wasn't this part of my code at all it was this line that I had in the rest of my css: ".contentModule { color: #FF00FF; border: 1px solid transparent; background: transparent; li  {cursor: pointer}}"

Comment: I had "...cursor: pointer; }" instead of "...li {cursor: pointer}}" Sooooo sorry for reposting this question as I will mark an answer based on the comments I just sent. :)

Answer (score 0):

That part of my code wasn't the problem at all. It was this line that I had as part of the rest of my css that I did not post on this question:

```
.contentModule { color: #FF00FF; border: 1px solid transparent; background: transparent; li {cursor: pointer}}"
```

I had "...cursor: pointer; }" instead of "...li {cursor: pointer}}".